# Can not access props in function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const OrderComplete = ({
stage
}) =>

const someFunction = () => { console.log(stage) }

useEffect(()=> setTimeout(()=>someFunction(),1000),[])
...
```

I am getting value of **stage** undefined. But if i use react dev tool and look to components props like

Value in the component

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use dependency array of `useEffect`:

```
const OrderComplete = ({
stage
}) =>

const someFunction = () => { console.log(stage) }

useEffect(()=> setTimeout(()=>someFunction(),1000),[someFunction])
```

Because if you pass an empty array, the callback will only take effect on initial render, when the `stage` prop might be `undefined`

Comment: Also i already did `[stage]` and it worked fine and tried your solution which is also great. Tested it, your solution is working too.